# How to show that if $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ converges, where $0<a_n<1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can we use ratio test here? Since $\sum a_n$ converges, $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$. There exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ for all $n \ge n$.

So, $a_{n+1}<a_n, \implies \frac{1-a_n}{1-a_{n+1}}<1$. Hence,

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\frac{1-a_n}{1-a_{n+1}}=\frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{1-a_{n+1}}}{\frac{a_{n}}{1-a_{n}}}<1$. But we take limit supremum then limit can be $1$. So, I couldn't conclude anything. Where I am missing? Am I going in a correct way?

Edit: Can someone suggest an counterexample for the converse?

Comment: A plain comparison test will do: $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n} < 2a_n$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Not unless you spend more than 55 seconds thinking about the hint.

Comment: We should use the fact $a_n \to 0$ to prove $a_n<\frac{1}{2}$ after a stage thats what you saying?

Comment: @MadhanKumar Since $\sum a_n$ is convergent $\sum 2a_n$ will also converge. Now you have $0<\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}<2a_n$ for all $n\geq K$ for some $K \in \mathbb N$. Therefore the convergence of $\sum 2a_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ by Comparison test.

Comment: That's what @Troposphere said.

Comment: $\sum a_n$ converges doesn't imply $\limsup\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$.

Comment: Ok get it. Thanks. Do you know any counter?

Comment: If $c_n=\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$, then $a_n=\frac{c_n}{1+c_n}<c_n$, so the converse is true also.